# RxJS Is Observer and Subscriber the same thing?

Tags: rxjs, observable

From this [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#observable):

> RxJS introduces Observables, a new Push system for JavaScript. An Observable is a Producer of multiple values, "pushing" them to Observers (Consumers).

> Subscribing to an Observable is analogous to calling a Function.

To invoke an Observable we should call the `subscribe()` function from the Observable object itself and pass the observer as the consumer of the data delivered by the observable like:

```
observable.subscribe( { /*this is an observer*/ } );
```

Also this [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observer) says:

> What is an Observer? An Observer is a consumer of values delivered by an Observable. Observers are simply a set of callbacks, one for each type of notification delivered by the Observable: next, error, and complete. The following is an example of a typical Observer object:

On the other hand the first documentation says:

> The Observable constructor takes one argument: the subscribe function.
> The following example creates an Observable to emit the string 'hi' every second to a subscriber.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const observable = new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {
  const id = setInterval(() => {
    subscriber.next('hi')
  }, 1000);
});
```

> When calling observable.subscribe with an Observer, the function subscribe in new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {...}) is run for that given subscriber. Each call to observable.subscribe triggers its own independent setup for that given subscriber.

So the entity `Subscriber` is just the argument passed into the subscribe function when creating a new Observable? If not who is the subscriber?

Are Observers and Subscribers the same entity? as mentioned in this [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscriber)

Why isn't the code that invokes `observable.subscribe({observer as call backs})` the subscriber of the observable? Like the consumer of a function's return value is the code that makes the function call.

---

[COMPLETE DESIGN PATTERN EXPLANATION](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer)

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, I think questions like these are useful. Your last link essentially explains it, though: Observer is the API for the contract of consuming an observable (next, error, complete), while Subscriber is 1) a specific implementation of observers and 2) used in RxJs to provide additional functionality. Notably, `subscribe` gets passed a (partial) observer which is then converted into a Subscriber.

Comment: @IngoBürk but why there is also subscriber in the observable creating function when creating an Observable?

Comment: No, the observer and the subscription are not the same thing. The documentation you linked to didn't say they were.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Observer

```ts
const observer = {
  next: v => /* code for next callback*/,
  error: err => /* code for error callback*/,
  complete: () => /* code for completion callback*/
}
```

## Subscription

```ts
const subscription = {
  unsubscribe: () => /* code for unsubscribe callback */
}
```

## Observable

```ts
const observable1 = from([1,2,3,4,5]);
const observable2 = of(1,2,3,4,5);
const observable3 = new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  observer.next(4);
  observer.next(5);
  observer.complete();

  return { // return a subscription
    unsubscribe: () => /* code for unsubscribe callback */
  };
});
```

## Subscribe and use the Returned Subscription

```ts
// Store a subscription 
const subscription = observable3.subscribe(observer);
// Invoke the unsubscribe callback defined by the observable.
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

## Okay. Then What is a Subscriber?

> [Subscriber] Implements the Observer interface and extends the Subscription class. While the Observer is the public API for consuming the values of an Observable, all Observers get converted to a Subscriber... Subscriber is a common type in RxJS, and crucial for implementing operators, but it is rarely used as a public API.

Are observers and subscribers the same thing? Kind of, yes? Depends on how concretely you ask the question.

Consider this:

```ts
observable3.subscribe({
  next: v => /* code for next callback */
});

obsevable3.subscribe(
  v => /* code for next callback */
);
```

The first is an object with only one observer property defined. The second is simply a lambda function. They both end up generating basically the same subscriber.

Comment: No, observers and subscriptions are distinct things. There are not the same or even kind of the same.

Comment: @Enigmativity You may have misread my answer. Subscribers are distinct from subscriptions. Both of which are lightly outlined in this post and expanded on further in the docs. The difference between subscribers and observers is a bit more subtle.

If you disagree, please create a new answer so future  visitors to this question can understand what ou mean.